# spring api-gateway changes secured port when redirecting

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

The Zuul api gateway redirects secured ports (8443,443) to 8080.
Example:
request : 
http://localhost:8443/auth
redirect : 
http://localhost:8080/auth

How can I solve this issue ?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here is a sample App, which works.
https://github.com/bredx27/zuul-sample
But when I add SSL to the api gateway (https), and change the port,
it fails.

Comment: What's the "issue"? Does it stop redirecting? You should use `https://localhost:9443/auth`.

Comment: It does the redirecting but not the way I want it.
Even if I use https it just redirects me to http://localhost:8080/auth
It changes the https to http and it changes the port from 8443 to 8080